# converting properties in a list using EMF databinding does not convert values

Tags: data-binding, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-databinding

I am trying to convert some values from integers to strings using a converter.

```
observerViewerValue = ViewerProperties.input().observe(tableViewer);
UpdateValueStrategy strategy = new UpdateValueStrategy();
strategy.setConverter(new ItemConverter());
IObservableValue observeItemValue = props[0].observe(peopleList);
bindingContext.bindValue(observerViewerValue, observeItemValue, strategy, strategy);

tableViewer.setInput(peopleList);
```

it doesn't like the fact that it has been given a list, I tried iterating through and doing:

`IObservableValue observeItemValue = props[0].observe(peopleList.get(i));`

where i is the index, no exceptions are thrown but the values aren't converted. `props[0]` just contains the property that will be watched.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overriding the `ObservableMapLabelProvider` and adding the converter in the `getColumnText` method, it did the trick...